# Create specific time variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter

With `TimeOfDay.now()` we can get the actual time, but how can we create a variable with a different time, like `12:00` for example?

I need to be able to select a DateTime manually but by default, I need to display 12pm.

Comment: Can you show some code what you have done till now.

Comment: it's just a variable declaration. What I tried doesn't work

Comment: `TimeOfDay(hour: 12, minute: 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do this:

`TimeOfDay(hour: 12, minute: 0)`

Comment: perfect. I also needed `format(context)` at the end the get `12:00 PM` on my widget

Answer (score 1):

Using String you can set custom time in following manner.

```
var moonLanding = DateTime.parse("2020-02-10 12:00:00Z");  
print(moonLanding.hour);
```